# How do I get a list of the connected wifi clients in OpenWrt 10.03?

Tags: linux, openwrt

I'm looking to be able to view the connected clients within the OpenWrt 10.03 software.

Answer (score 8):

Like explained here - [OpenWrt logging: how to find out "wifi deauthentication"](https://superuser.com/questions/236866/openwrt-logging-how-to-find-out-wifi-deauthentication/243411#243411) - it depends on the wireless driver you're using.

- `iw dev wlan0 station dump` --> for `nl80211/mac80211` compatible drivers
- `wlc assoclist` --> for proprietary `broadcom-wl` driver

In case of `iw` you naturally need to replace `wlan0` with the interface that has `hostapd` (AP daemon) running on it.

---

**Update**

We're about to see 15.05.1 soon and since quite a few releases ago there is also `libiwinfo`: a great little abstraction layer to all major backend interfaces (currently *Broadcom, Madwifi, nl80211 and wext*). This is now the recommended way of getting information from the wireless subsystem.

It comes with a command-line utility (package `iwinfo`):

```
iwinfo wlan0 assoclist
```

There's also Lua bindings (package `libiwinfo-lua`) if you're scripting:

```
require("iwinfo")
iface = "wlan0"
t = iwinfo.type(iface)
clients = iwinfo[t].assoclist(iface)
for k,v in pairs(clients) do print(k, v.signal) end
--> 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   -44
--> 0A:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   -67
--> ....
```

There is even an `ubus` interface to `iwinfo` if you're up to something clever (package `rpcd`, [docs](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/ubus?s[]=iwinfo#rpcd)).