# Log Web Traffic on OpenWRT

Tags: proxy, logging, openwrt

Is it possible to to log web requests on OpenWRT? I'm pretty sure I could do it on DD-WRT.

What I would like to to see the urls. Would I have to set up a proxy to do that, or does OpenWRT have that option?

Comment: I hope these help.
http://superuser.com/questions/632898/how-to-log-all-dns-requests-made-through-openwrt-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this : `tcpdump -A -s 0 'tcp port 80' -w logfile.dump`, then analyse the output using `wireshark`.

Please keep in mind that a growing part of the internet traffic is encrypted using `https` and so you won't be able to decrypt those requests.