# Dnsmasq: Log all DNS queries from specific IP/device

Tags: dnsmasq, tracking

I use Dnsmasq to resolve DNS queries in my local network. To prevent the TV from loading ads/tracking me, I set up dnsmasq to resolve [dozens of domains](https://gist.github.com/hkamran80/779019103fcd306979411d44c8d38459) to localhost.

However, this has downsides. TV now regularly complains that it is not connected to the web. To investigate which of those blocked domains should be allowed to go through, a list of domain requests made by the TV is needed.

So how can I set up DNSmasq to log **the TVs requests** into a file/systemlog/somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log all DNS requests made through OpenWRT router?](https://superuser.com/questions/632898/how-to-log-all-dns-requests-made-through-openwrt-router)

Comment: I saw this answer. But If I understand it right, it logs every query into a global log/file. I would rather only log the queries of specific devices.

Comment: You can look at the options for `dnsmasq` [here](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) but glancing over them, I didn't see any built-in options for logging only certain devices. My guess is you may have to do some filtering on your own, whether that is some real-time implementation or e.g. simply grepping for the local IP(s) you want later.